# I would like to know how to make class based views for my existing model forms. I need to redirect the form one model form to the other

Tags: python, django

#### These contains semester, subject, assesment etc, which are all linked to each other by foreign key

#### models.py

```
from django.db import models
class Semester(models.Model):
    S_OPTIONS = (
        ('1', '1'),
        ('2', '2'),
        ('3', '3'),
        ('4', '4'),
        ('5', '5'),
        ('6', '6'),
        ('7', '7'),
        ('8', '8'),
    )
    sem_type=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=S_OPTIONS)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sem_type
class Subject(models.Model):
    S_OPTIONS = (
        ('Math','Math'),
        ('English','English'),
        ('C++','C++'),
        ('Thermo','Thermo'),
        ('Electronics', 'Electronics'),
    )
    sub_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, choices= S_OPTIONS)
    sem = models.ForeignKey(Semester, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.sub_type
class Assesment(models.Model):
    A_OPTIONS = (
        ('1','CT1'),
        ('2','CT2'),
        ('3','CT3'),
    )
    assess_type=models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=A_OPTIONS)
    sub = models.ForeignKey(Subject, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)
    def __str__(self):
        return self.assess_type
class Paper(models.Model):
    PA_OPTIONS = (
        ('1','1'),
        ('2','2'),
    )
    paper_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=PA_OPTIONS,default=1)
    assesment = models.ForeignKey(Assesment, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

  #  def get_absolute_url(self):
   #     return reverse('teacher:home',kwargs={'pk': self.pk})

    def __str__(self):
        return self.paper_type
class Part(models.Model):
    P_OPTIONS = (
        ('A','A'),
        ('B','B'),
        ('C','C'),

    )
    part_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=P_OPTIONS)
    paper= models.ForeignKey(Paper, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.part_type
class Question(models.Model):
    a = models.TextField()
    part= models.ForeignKey(Part,on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=1)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.a
class Choice(models.Model):
    c = models.TextField(null= True)
    question = models.ForeignKey(Question, on_delete =models.CASCADE,default=1, null =True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.c
```

#### after submitting each form, in the vews, they must redirect to next modelform

#### forms.py

```
from django import forms
from .models import Semester,Subject,Assesment,Paper,Part,Question,Choice
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class SemesterForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Semester
        fields = ['sem_type',]

class SubjectForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Subject
        fields = ['sub_type',]

class AssesmentForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Assesment
        fields = ['assess_type',]

class PaperForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Paper
        fields = ['paper_type',]

class PartForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Part
        fields = ['part_type',]

class QuestionForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Question
        fields = ['a',]


class ChoiceForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Choice
        fields = ['c',]
```

#### how should I write the views such that I can get data and redirect to the next model form using a template? please help. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use `FormView`, like the below example, for each form you want the user to fill.

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.views.generic import FormView
from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
from .forms import SemesterForm


class SemesterFormView(FormView):
    success_url = reverse_lazy("<your next view>")
    template_name = "<your template name>"
    form_class = SemesterForm

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.save()  # or any other business logic you need 
        return HttpResponseRedirect(self.get_success_url())
```

This way you use the success redirect to send the user to the view of that renders the next form.

Comment: The last line "HttpResponseRedirect" shows an error. What does it do?

Comment: @Aravind it was missing an import. I edited the answer to correct it. The `HttpResponseRedirect` redirects the user to the next form (`sucess_url`), in this case when the form is valid.